# pointer in function scope crash

Tags: c++, pointers, matrix, double

I was trying to do some naughty things in class and got a crash which i couldn't solve. I believe it is caused by trying to read unallocated data, even though I think the data should be allocated and filled. help..?

```
   void read(int &n, int &m, double ** arr){
    fstream f1;
    f1.open("1.txt"); //open a file to read the data from it
    f1>>n>>m;

    arr = new double *[n];//create an array of pointers (double)

    for(int e = 0; e<n; e++){
        arr[e] = new double[m]; //assign arrays of doubles to each pointer in the array
        for(int l = 0; l < m; l++){
            arr[e][l]= 0.f; //set it to 0
        }
    }
    for(int e = 0; e<n; e++){
        for(int s = 0; s<m; s++){
            f1>>arr[e][s]; //read it from file
        }
    }
    f1.close();
    cout<<arr[3][4]<<"\n"; //prints out fine (the last number in my test matrix)
}

int main(){
    double ** matrix;
    read(n, m, matrix); //fills the matrix
    cout<<matrix[0][0]; //crashes the program

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are sending `matrix` as parameter, it is being copied by value to `arr`. Then in `read()` memory is allocated and processing is done. When `read()` ends, it just destroys `arr` pointer i.e. which is not `matrix` exactly, now we are back in `main()` and `matrix` is still non-allocated (`nullptr` in debug mode). Return `arr` from `read()` to `main()` and store it in `matrix`. Return type of `read()` should be `double**` in this case. Do not forget to `delete` matrix properly in `main()` then.

**EDIT:**

A pointer has physical memory in RAM. `matrix` has its own physical memory, call it 0xAAAA and `arr` has its own memory in RAM, call it 0xBBBB. When `matrix` is passed to `read()`, a new double pointer is created in RAM which is not same as `matrix`, this new pointer is known by `arr` in your case. To confirm it, use `cout << &matrix;` and `cout << &arr;` and you'll see they are at two different locations. Now when `read()` is called, the **contents** of `matrix` are copied to `arr` after its creation. At the time of calling `read()`, `matrix` is null i.e. points to 0x0000 location, contents copying mean now `arr` points to same location which is 0x0000 or null. Confirm it by using `cout << matrix;` and `cout << arr` and the results will be same. Now you allocate new memory for `arr`. `matrix` does not know about this memory, it still is pointing to 0x0000. When `read()` ends, `arr` is destroyed, but not **contents** of `arr`. The memory which was allocated using `new` keyword is now pointed by no pointer. When control gets back to `main()` after `read()` ends, `matrix` is still pointing to 0x0000. You want to access it and get error. Now there must be a way by which you can point `matrix` to memory allocated by `arr` or else it will be a memory leak. There are a number of ways, 1 of them is to return contents of `arr, other is to allocate memory in`main()`, process using`read()`and again access memory after`read()` ends.

Comment: Again isn't `matrix` a physical address in ram? Can I make it so I don't have to return anything? I'm sorry if this is primitive stuff but I want to know whats going on under the hood here

Comment: let me edit my answer and add some details about "under the hood" thing

Comment: I did not add details about **Memory Leak** and correct deletion of `matrix`. Good practice is to always `delete` the memory allocated by `new` to avoid memory leaks.

Answer (score 0):

You allocate memory for `arr` in `read`, but try to use it in `main`. If you want to use arr as an out parameter (like `n` or `m`), you should make it a reference.

Comment: Can you elaborate? I thought that pointer are much like references here. I assumed that I get the actual address with `matrix` as an argument and then just fill space there with data. How am I supposed to use a reference here?